# Pandas with RegExp Producing Leading and Trailing NAN columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4

I have some simple data in a file that I'm reading in with pandas:

```
2018:08:23:07:35:22:INFO:__main__:Info logger message
```

There are no beginning or trailing tabs, spaces, etc. in the file.

I read that file into a dataframe using the following:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("/u01/app/DataLake/tester/tester.log", header=None, index_col=False, sep=r'(\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):(.+):(.+):(.+)',engine='python')
```

However, I'm getting the following:

```
>>> print(df)
     0                    1        2         3                       4   5
0  NaN  2018:08:23:07:35:22     INFO  __main__     Info logger message NaN
```

Where is the first and last column (NaN values) coming from?

Python: 3.4.8
Pandas: 0.19.2

Comment: You can remove the `NaN` columns with `df.dropna(axis=1)`

Comment: @rahlf23 thanks!   I could not get the `dropna` command to work (maybe my old version of Pandas), but I was able to use `df.drop([0,5], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: Glad you found a solution! You could change the `5` to `-1` to always ensure it will be the last column as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually surprised that your regex even worked! 
The `sep` parameter is for identifying **where** to split, not **what** tokens to recognize. 
What you really want (actually, an equivalent for what you want) is a regex that can:

- Split on every space.
- Split on `:` , unless the next 2 characters are digits followed by another `:`.

That can be achieved using some advanced regex matching, specifically "lookahead". See [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) for a detailed explanation of that.

This should work for your example:

```
pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, sep=' |:(?!\d{2}:)', header=None, engine='python')
```